# use of app file in products folder in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I wish to know the usage of .app file that comes in products folder while creating an xcode project for iOS.

app file appears red when run in simulator, but appears when run in device.

I right clicked on this file while running it in device. Now how can I use this app file?
What is the use of this file? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What's sometimes useful is to check all assets that get copied into your app bundle. Right-click the file and click 'Show in finder'. Then when you right-click it and 'Show package contents' you can browse all the files that got copied into your target app. If something is missing there you didn't add it to your target.

Other then that, XCode manages the installation of your app file on the device and in the simulator, and when you create an Ad-hoc/Appstore archive so you basically don't need to use it.

The fact that it is red means it doesn't exist (yet). Since it refers to the build product of the device and not simulator it's only created after you have build your project for iOS device.

Comment: ok so does that mean if i give this app file to my friend, then he can run it on his device/ simulator?